# Wide pushups vs narrow - what are the outcomes?

Tags: exercise, chest, strength-training

I wonder whats the difference of outcome (in like 6 months) if a person does wide *pushups* vs narrow ones?

Whats the outcome of the size of chest (and triceps), strength etc.

Answer (score 1):

The wide push-up recruits more of your pectoral muscles while a regular push-up shares the burden with your triceps muscles. According to a small study of eight people, when subjects dropped to their knees to modify the wide push-up, also known as the abduction push-up, they saw a drop in overall muscle activation in the upper body. However, when the same scientists studied the narrow push-up, or adduction push-up, they saw an increase in upper body muscle activation, even though the subjects were modifying on their knees. Thus, they concluded that the narrow push-up is more challenging than the wide push-up.

http://www.livestrong.com/article/433267-push-ups-elbows-in-vs-out/